# Why event not fired when I change selection on DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dropdown

I have this asp net drp box:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLayersList"
        runat="server"
        BackColor="#FFFFC0"
        CssClass="form-control fullwidth" OnTextChanged="ddlLayersList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is how I fill the drop box:

```
private void SetLayers(Dictionary<string, string> layers)
{
    ddlLayersList.DataSource = layers;
    ddlLayersList.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddlLayersList.DataTextField = "Value";
    ddlLayersList.DataBind();
    ddlLayersList.Items.Insert(0, "-Select Item-");
}
```

And here is code behind event:

```
protected void ddlLayersList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

When I select item from drop box the event not fired.
Any idea why event not fired when I change selection on `DropDownList`?

Comment: You bind it to OnTextChanged instead of OnSelectedIndexChanged, that might be the case. Also try setting AutoPostBack to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [AutoPostBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to `True`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLayersList" AutoPostBack="True">
```

The value of this property:

> true if a postback to the server automatically occurs whenever the
>   user changes the selection of the list; otherwise, false. The default
>   is false

Also you need to set the [`OnSelectedIndexChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event instead of `OnTextChanged`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLayersList" 
       AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLayersList_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides on setting `AutoPostBack="true"` to enable automatic postback, also set `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler instead of `OnTextChanged` (note that both of them are not the same event):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLayersList"
           runat="server"
           BackColor="#FFFFC0"
           AutoPostBack="true"
           CssClass="form-control fullwidth" 
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLayersList_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```