# Unable to update changes in a web application using SelectedIndexChanged (DropDownList)

Tags: c#, type-conversion, listitem, selectedindexchanged

So I've written a program where the number of letters of a city name from a drop down list are multiplied to a certain constant.
However it doesn't update.

Here is the html:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Destinacii" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="76px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Destinacii_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

Price: <asp:Label ID="Price" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
```

Here is the c# code:

```
protected void Destinacii_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = Destinacii.SelectedItem.Text;
            int price = (2000 * text.Length);

            Price.Text = price.ToString();
        }
```

P.S. I've added the items in c#, not in the html.

Answer (score 0):

From [Why event not fired when I change selection on DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041100/why-event-not-fired-when-i-change-selection-on-dropdownlist/53041139#53041139):

You need to set the `AutoPostBack` property to `True` in your `DropDownList` like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Destinacii" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="76px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Destinacii_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>

Price: <asp:Label ID="Price" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
```